# How to resize the image before base64 conversion

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

In my sencha based application i want to convert the image into base64,Before that i want to resize the original one.Here the code which i have used to convert base64

```
function getBase64FromImageUrl(URL)
{
var img = new Image();
img.style.width = '5%',
img.style.height = '5%',
img.src = URL;
img.onload = function ()
{
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width =this.width;
    canvas.height =this.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 10, 10);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
    if(App.gvars.userpic=='1')
    {
    cdd=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }
    if(App.gvars.userpic=='2')
    {
    c=dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }
   }
}
```

How to resize or redimension the image before conversion?I have tried with changing img.style.width and hieght but there is no change at all.Please help me

Comment: Please check the additional optional parameters for drawImage ... you can resize the image on the canvas directly while drawing it. The resulting dataURL will reflect the resized image. And remember to reduce canvas.width and canvas.height accordingly

Comment: @devnull69 any examples?

Answer (score 0):

Per devnull69's suggestion, simply use drawImage() to resize the image when you add it into the canvas.

See the API at either [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can even play with the values in a live-coding example at [Html5CanvasTutorials](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/)